# The Phrase “But That”

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

Reading the last sentence of Ellison’s *Invisible Man*, I stumbled a bit on the phrase “but that:”

> Being invisible and without substance, a disembodied voice, as it were, what else could I do? What else but try to tell you what was really happening when your eyes were looking through? And it is this which frightens me: **Who knows but that, on lower frequencies, I speak for you?**

A compelling sentence, but I’m not so sure of the meaning of “but that.” My dictionary says another phrase, “to the contrary,” can be substituted for it. But if I were to guess now, Ellison’s narrator seems to be saying, with some apprehension: “Who knows for certain that, on lower frequencies, I don’t speak for you?”

Comment: [Collins dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/but-that) *Am. Eng.* **but that:** "that there is not some chance that". I'm American, and your dictionary's definition seems quite wrong to me. Maybe it doesn't cover American English.

Comment: So your guess at the meaning is quite accurate.

Comment: Collins dictionary online has the same definition; I see it now. Thank you! Is this an older American idiom?

Comment: *To the contrary* is the normal use of *but*, like *however*. Here it means *except* that I could be speaking for you: "There but for the grace of God go I."

Comment: Thank you as well! Refreshing my memory of that phrase, I see it means “except” or “if it weren’t for.” Does that fit the last sentence? Sorry to be obtuse, but it’s probably worthwhile understanding this thoroughly.

Comment: Please add the actual quote, a linked attribution to the definition you used; accuracy and context can then be checked. Obviously, in "He said not that I was ancient, but that I was getting on a bit", we have a different situation, showing contradiction ('but on the contrary that', 'but rather that').